# When did this Kali yuga start?

Tags: yuga, kali-yuga, calendar

Is there a way to know the start date in Gregorian calendar of current Kali yuga? If yes,  What is the date?

Comment: @ssr1012 Good one!! Any way to know apporx date or year?

Comment: It started after Sri Krishna left earth. Believed to be february 18, 3102 BC.

Comment: You can check my answer here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58627/24460 on this question, I have quoted śāstras. Thanks @TheDestroyer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with the age of `Kali Yuga`, is 4,32,000 years. Till now 5115 years have passed. The Wiki article says : According to the [Surya Siddhanta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surya_Siddhanta), Kali Yuga began at midnight (00:00) on 18 February 3102 BCE. This is also considered the date on which Lord Krishna left the earth to return to his heavenly abode.

According to the astronomer and mathematician Aryabhatta the Kali Yuga started in 3102 BCE. He finished his book `Aryabhattiya` in 499 CE, in which he gives the exact year of the beginning of Kali Yuga. He writes that he wrote the book in the `year 3600 of the Kali Age` at the age of 23.

So this is the partly story of the day:

> On 18 February 3102 BCE Lord Krishn went to a forest near Prabhasa theertham (the junction point where Gomathi river joins the sea), in Gujarat to meditate, in his chariot driven by Dharuka. Once reached there, he told Dharuka: **Go back. Inform all those left in Dwaraka, that it would be shortly submerged by ocean as Dwapara Yug was ending and that all should move to other places for safety…**. After Dharuka left, In the forest, Sri Krishn witnessed his brother Sri Balram attain `videha mukti` (consciously and intentionally leaving one’s body). After this he wandered about immersed in deep thought and finally began to accept his destiny. Then Krishna sat down to meditate.
>
> When Jara, mistook Krishna for a deer and shot an arrow into his foot, came and saw Krishna he was shocked and asked for forgiveness. Krishna  smiled at him and said **You need not repent, because you were Bali in your previous birth and I as Rama had killed you in Tretayuga. Now, I have to leave this body and was waiting for an opportunity to end my life. I was waiting for you so that the karmic debt between you and me is finished. Since all acts in this world are done as desired by me, you need not worry for this**.
>
> Still, on realizing his grave error he was filled with remorse and grief. But Krishna consoled him and said - **Don't be scared or sorry as these were the ways of destiny**. Those were the great Lord’s last words on earth.

The time stood still on February 18, 3102 BC Friday at 02 hours, 27 minutes and 30 seconds in the afternoon. His death marked the end of Dwapar yuga. The period after his disappearance marks the first day of Kali Yug.

Also refer [The beginning of Kaliyug](http://www.encyclopediaofauthentichinduism.org/articles/51_the_bhartiya_chronology.htm).

Comment: Sūryasiddhānta doesn't mention February 18, 3102 BCE date for start of Kaliyuga. If it does so, please quote the relevant śloka. I have posted an answer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58627/24460 on this question, which you may check, if interested. Thanks