# How is the date of Aryabhata calculated?

Tags: history, kali-yuga

Kali Yuga is [said](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16383/when-did-this-kali-yuga-start/16403#16403) to start at around 3000 BCE because Aryabhata said he is living 3600 years into Kali Yuga.

But how do we know when Aryabhata lived?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In his book Aryabhatiya, he mentions the following:

[image]

**Meaning**:

> "When the three yugas Satya yuga, Treta yuga and Dwapara yuga) have elapsed and
>   60 x 60 (3,600) years of Kali yuga have already passed, I am now 23
>   years old".

Calculate accordingly:

- He said in his book that 3600 years of Kali have passed. It means
  when he wrote the book, 3600 years of Kali have elapsed.
- He further added that he was 23 years old when he completed his book.
  So, when he was born, 3577 (3600-23) years of Kali might have passed.
- In Panchankam, through astrology, it is mentioned that as of April
  2018, 5119 years of Kali have passed. Now, subtract 3577 from 5119.
  You will get the number 1542. It means, 1542 years have elapsed since
  Aryabhatta was born.
- Now reduce 1542 from 2018. You will get 476. This is how, his date is
  calculated.

Comment: Thanks. But do Western scholars calculate it this way? The reason is because Western scholars don't believe in Yuga theory, and so they don't believe that Kali yuga started around 5000 BCE. So how do they calculate his date?

Comment: @Ikshvaku Western scholars definitely don't believe neither in Yugas nor in astrology. But Aryabhatta might have believed in both, as he was a Brahmin and he himself mentioned in his book about Yugas. He might have used astrology to determine the age of Kali when he wrote his book, similar to how present day astrologers determine.