# What is the scriptural basis on which it is said that Kaliyuga started in about 3000 BC?

Tags: kali-yuga

On what scriptural basis it is said that Kaliyuga started in 3000 BC ? I don't think any such date is written in any scripture.

How this rumour of Kaliyuga starting in 3000 BC begun ?

Comment: Aryabhatta stated in his treatise that xyz number of years have passed since Kaliyuga began. So by dating Aryabhatiya to the Śaka & Vikrama years, we can back-calculate the date of Kaliyuga's beginning.

Comment: @blue_ego in kaliyug, a woman named maya thought about elephant and became pregnant. Full science saar.  Also krsa didn't invaded earth.

Comment: Your question is an exact duplicate and it already has an answer now here [Do any scriptures mention the date when Kaliyuga started?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/54006/do-any-scriptures-mention-the-date-when-kaliyuga-started)

Comment: You can check my answer here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58627/24460 , I have quoted śāstras. Thanks @অনু

Comment: @Hope You may too check the answer. Thanks

Comment: and if you are interested, you may check as well @blue_ego  Thanks